# Problem with load cell and ADS1262

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using [PROTOCENTRAL ADS1262 32-BIT PRECISION ADC BREAKOUT BOARD](https://www.protocentral.com/breakout-boards/1005-protocentral-ads1262-32-bit-precision-adc-breakout-board.html) to read the voltage in simple a load cell.

The connections follows the instructions on its library

But I cannot make it work, the readings has lots of spikes and i cannot discover what is happening.

Can someone help?

[image: Reading from ADS1262]

Comment: That is a very hard question to answer. Every pulse is followed by a slope, that means it could be an analog charge that is released. Can you do more tests ? Beside the spikes, can you actually measure the analog signal ? What happens if you shortcut the inputs ? Do you use the library provided by ProCentral ? Have you enabled the right 50Hz or 60Hz noise suppression ? How large are those spikes ? Have you tried a different power supply ? The ADS1262 has test modes, perhaps you can try one of them. The datasheet is very long. It will not be easy to fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem was solved on Texas Instruments Forum.
Thanks.

http://e2e.ti.com/support/data_converters/precision_data_converters/f/73/p/627185/2344271#2344271

---

From the TI forum:

> I noticed that you are polling data ready and then performing the data processing/serial output. The serial output operation is likely taking a long time and preventing you from capturing data at the faster data rates. You can try disabling the serial output and using an oscilloscope to see if you're able to reading data at the full throughput; however, when outputting this data over a serial interface you might not be able to capture and display all of the data...
>
> I would try capturing data to memory and outputting the serial data in batches (for example, output 10 samples of data at a time). This might give you a little more data throughput.